# How to execute a shellscript from java from a specific user

Tags: java, shell, jakarta-ee

I am calling a shellscript using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

My script is called  properly but it executes as root user, I want to call it with some other user ?

How can I do that?

My command is like:

`String wrapper_script="homedir+"/blast_distribute.sh "+" --seqs="+seqs+" --i="+formobj.getUpFile().getFileName()+" "+formobj.getSelected_program();`

and than I use : `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(wrapper_script);`

Comment: I am using Centos 6.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spawned process will be executed as the same user running the JVM. Depending on your application it is probably not a good idea if it is run as root.

But if it is, you can use Linux commands to change to another user, for example:

```
su <user> -c "<command>"
```

will run `<command>` as the user `<user>`.

Comment: My command is like  String wrapper_script="homedir+"/blast_distribute.sh "+" --seqs="+seqs+" --i="+formobj.getUpFile().getFileName()+"  "+formobj.getSelected_program();  and than I use : Runtime.getRuntime().exec(wrapper_script); How should I modify my code?

Comment: I have tried String wrapper_script="su username -c "+ "homedir+"/blast_distribute.sh "+" --seqs="+seqs+" --i="+formobj.getUpFile().getFileName()+" "+formobj.getSelected_program(); but it did't work

Comment: Did you properly escape all the `"`?

Comment: yes ...I think that when It sees su username,It switch to other user,And rest of command is not executed

Comment: Does the other user have a valid home directory and shell specified in /etc/passwd?

Comment: yes,When I execute that scrit by that user on shell, It works properly

Comment: Yes your are right.Probably it gets executed , but it does's recognize --seqs option than

Comment: If I do that ,It does't take any of parameters entered with script

Comment: The command needs to be quoted, not sure if you did that. For example `su user -c "ls -l"`. Without the quotes it does not recognize the parameters as belonging to the command.

Comment: Yes , I did't .If my syntax is like : String s="ls -l"+/home/abhijeet and than I use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su - "+username+" -c "+s); How to quote command in it? How to quote s in it? if i Do 's' .It will take as string  right? It will not take its quoted value

Comment: Use something like `"su "+username+" -c \""+s + "\""`. But this will only work if there are no `"` characters in `s`.

Comment: That is the problem , that I have " " in s :(

Comment: Then try single quotes: `"su "+username+" -c '"+s + "'"`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
runuser -l  userName -c 'command'
```

in exec( ) function.

Here is the snapshot of command I ran

[image]

Or if you want to run specific command from specific path use like

```
runuser -l  userName -c 'path/to/Dir/command arg arg2 arg2'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've `sudo` installed on your machine, add the appropriate user to `/etc/sudoers` and then you can use  use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo -u your-user your-command")`